# Proof verification about homomorphisms and groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

In my last homework, I didn't get full credit in my proofs even though I got the right idea. My TA's comments were:

- Clearly state where each proof begins an ends. Write complete sentences
- Good job. I just need more justification and precision. Be more rigorous.

He wants me to justify every step because I am just starting writing proofs, so I am just wondering if you can give me feedback based on that criteria. I tried to  fit that criteria on the following proof. I don't even know if I did it right, so I also need feedback on the main ideas.

4.14 Proposition Let $f: G\rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism between groups $G$ and $H$

a) If $U$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $f(U)$ is a subgroup of H.

Proof (a)

To show that $f(U)$ is a subgroup of H, we need to show three things:
1)$1_H \in f(U)$
2)for all $a,b \in f(U)$ also $a*b$ lies in $f(U)$
3) for all $a\in f(U)$, $a^{-1}$ also lies in $f(U)$

Note: We will be using * as the standard operation on the two groups

1)We know that $1_G \in U$ because $U$ is a subgroup of G and by definition a subgroup must contain the identity element of it's parent group. $U$ is closed, so we can say $1_G *1_G \in U$. $e_G *e_G=e_G$ because by definition the product of some element with the identity is the element itself. Therefore,
$$f(1_G)=f(1_G *1_G)$$

$f$ is a homomorphism between the $G$ and $H$, so we can say
$$f(1_G)=f(1_G*1_G)=f(1_G)*f(1_G)$$

If we multiply both sides by $f^{-1}(1_G)$, we get
$$f^{-1}(1_G)*f(1_G)=f^{-1}(1_G)*(f(1_G)*f(1_G))$$

Since $f^{-1}(1_G),f(1_G) \in H$, $f^{-1}(1_G)*f(1_G)=1_H$, so

$1_H=f^{-1}(1_G)*(f(1_G)*f(1_G))$
$1_H=(f^{-1}(1_G)*f(1_G))*f(1_G) \text{ by associativity }$
$1_H=(e_H)*f(1_G) \text{ this was already shown } $
$1_H=f(1_G) \text{ by properties of the identity element} $

$1_G \in U$, so $1_H \in f(U)$ which proves the first premise of the proposition

2) Let $a,b \in f(U)$, so $\exists x,y \in U$ such that $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$. Since $U$ is closed $x*y \in U$ and $f$ is a homomorphism between $G$ and $H$, so we can say
$$f(x*y)=f(x)*f(y)$$

and since $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$, we can say

$$f(x*y)=a*b$$

We can see that $f(x*y)\in f(U)$ since $x*y\in U$. Therefore, $a*b \in f(U)$ which proves the second premise

3) Let $a \in f(U)$, so $\exists x\in U$ such that $f(x)=a$. $x\in U$, so $x^{-1}\in U$ because $U$ is a subgroup and we also know $x*x^{-1} \in U$ because U is closed. Since $f$ is a homomorphism between $G$ and $H$ we can say  $$f(x*x^{-1})=f(x)*f(x^{-1})$$

but we know that $x*x^{-1}=1_G$ and we already showed that $f(1_G)=e_H$, so 
$$1_H=a*f(x^{-1})$$

$a\in f(U)$, $f(x^{-1})\in f(U)$ since $x^{-1}\in U$ and their product is $1_H$. This implies that $f(x^{-1})=a^{-1}$ and $a^{-1} \in f(U)$ which proves the third premise

Comment: I'm not sure if you've proven this yet in your class, but a fairly nice result is: $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ iff for every $a,b\in H$ we have $a*b^{-1}\in H$.  This could greatly simplify your work.

Comment: Uhmmm, we haven't proven that yet, but it looks very nice.

Comment: And another note:  Don't use $f^{-1}(1_G)$ to denote the inverse of $f(1_G)$, use $f(1_G)^{-1}$.  The former can be mistaken as meaning the preimage of $1_G$ under $f$.

Comment: Condition (1) can be dispensed with if we know $\text{im }f$ is non-empty, because it follows from (2) and (3): if $a \in f(U)$, and also $a^{-1} \in f(U)$, by (2): $a \ast a^{-1} = 1_H \in f(U)$. Also, decide on a notation for the identity of $H$-either $1_H$ or $e_H$, and be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you first part is wrong. To verify that $f(1_{G})$ is identity of $H$, by definition of identity, you have to show that $a*f(1_{G})=f(1_{G})*a=a$ for all $a\in f(U)$. I believe you can prove this.

Comment: That's  a little incomplete: you also then need the following lemma: If $K$ is a subgroup of $H$, then $e_K = e_H$.